# Pass data from Parent List to Child List on a new subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sub-site

I currently have a list where you can check a checkbox and it will create a sub-site for that list item.

This uses a standard template for each sub-site that has been heavily customized.

What i'm trying to do is pass information from that parent list item down into a list inside the sub-site that will store information pertaining to the parent list such as "Start Date", "Title" etc...

Is there a way to pull that data down into a subsite such as pausing the workflow after it's created the subsite, then create a list item inside a list? Or any other method.

I'm effectively wanting to pass some of the parent list data down the subsite programmatically as and when the subsite is being created not manually afterwards.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from parent list to child list, you could go to site settings->site administration->content and structure->click the parent list and select the list items->click actions and select the copy or move->select the child list and click ok.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Amy, I probably should have been more specific. I'm looking to do exactly as you've listed but programmatically when i create the sub-site not manually after its been created.

Comment: You could create event receiver and trigger the event to copy list items from parent list to child list when the site is created.
refer to the articles below.
http://www.fivenumber.com/copy-sharepoint-list-items-from-one-site-to-another-programmatically/ 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/